# SharePoint Online, turn off user access approval

Tags: sharepoint-online, external-users, external-sharing

Can I disable this approval feature?

[image]

I need to instantly give access for external user (I am admin). On the other hand - I don't need *members* to give access, so unchecked these two checkboxes

[image]

I remeber there was, a setting in SharePoint Admin Center, but now they make changes every week

Comment: There was something like "Share without invitation", if I remember right.. But I don't see this option now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either disable option 'Allow access requests' which will give user access denied and they can manually request for access on basis of any tickets or internal process. Or, you can mention email address of user who can approve the request. For remaining users, it will not allow to approve any user access request.

Comment: Thank You Goldi! I'll think what is better..